# Knex erro de migração

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sqlite3, migrations

Estou com problema com a migração no Knex e não sei o que pode ser.

**Log:**

```
migration file "20230416145155_createNotes.js" failed
migration failed with error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultTo')
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultTo')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultTo')
```

**Código com erro:**

**20230416145155_createNotes.js**

```js
/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('notes', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.text('title');
    table.text('description');
    table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users');
    table.timestamps('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamps('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  });
};

/**
 * @param { import("knex").Knex } knex
 * @returns { Promise<void> }
 */
exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('notes');
};
```

**knexfile.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'database.db')
    },
    pool: {
      afterCreate: (conn, callback) => conn.run("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", callback)
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'knex', 'migrations')
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true,
  }
};
```

**Informações**

```
OS: Windows 11
pnpm: 8.2.0
Knex ^2.4.2
Sqlite ^4.1.2
Sqlite3 ^5.1.6
```

**Comando**

```sh
npx knex migrate:latest
```

O estranho que a propriedade **defaultTo** existe, mas por algum motivo não esta funcionando.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá, o erro está ocorrendo pois você está utilizando a função de uma maneira errada para criar a tabela. Vamos lá explicar os dois modos:

**1ª modo:**

Primeiro vamos falar da função que você está utilizando, a `.timestamps()`. Essa função é utilizada para criar automaticamente os campos `created_at` e `updated_at` na tabela. Essa função pode receber 3 argumentos:

`table.timestamps([useTimestamps], [defaultToNow], [useCamelCase])`

Para fazer da forma que você deseja você deve usar a função da seguinte forma:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('notes', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.text('title');
    table.text('description');
    table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users');
    table.timestamps(true, true);
  });
};
```

[Documentação `.timestamps()`](https://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#timestamps)

**2º modo (A forma que você está tentando utilizar):**

Existe também outra função que você pode adicionar a coluna de uma forma mais "livre" por assim dizer. E essa função é a `.timestamp()` (só muda o plural mesmo). Essa função não cria os campos automaticamente, e pode receber 2 argumentos:

`table.timestamp(name, options={[useTz: boolean], [precision: number]})`

Com essa função, seu código funcionaria da mesma forma que está tentando realizar, só seria necessário aplicar a função no lugar da função que está sendo utilizada hoje:

```js
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('notes', table => {
    table.increments('id');
    table.text('title');
    table.text('description');
    table.integer('user_id').references('id').inTable('users');
    table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  });
};
```

[Documentação `.timestamp()`](https://knexjs.org/guide/schema-builder.html#timestamp)

Comment: Funcionou amigo, obrigado.